# how can append db values to a href (phonegap)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, phonegap-build

this my html page **nextPage.html** 
im lookig to display db values **category_id**, **category_name** which are from php controller in my html page. By clicking on **category_name** i want to go to the next html page and also my **category_id** will be passed to that page

pls help me.....pls

```
   </div> 
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

            <form id="nextForm" > 
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="category">      
              <li>
               <a></a>

              </li> 

            </ul>           
            </form>
    </div>
```

my js is **nextPage.js**

```
var base_url = "http://dev.edfutura.com/nithin/jps/edfuturaMob/";
$(document).on("pageinit", "#catlist", function() {


        var submitUrl = base_url + "categorylist/get_categorylist";


        //$("#loading").css("display", "block");  


        $.ajax({
            url: submitUrl,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                // do something pls
            },

            error: function() {
                alert("error");

            }



        });
```

controller **categorylist.php**

```
function get_categorylist() {

  $cat = $this - > categorylist_model - > get_cat();

  echo json_encode($cat);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can save data in sessionStorage and paint it when you want:

```
var session = (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") ? window.sessionStorage : null;
   $.ajax({
        url: submitUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            if(session) {
                // fill here data that you want
                session.setItem("data", response.data); 
            }
        },

        error: function() {
            alert("error");

        }
    });
```

To read it:

```
   if(session) { alert(session.getItem("data"); }
```

Good luck